# Sonata Admin Bundle: Dependencies & sonata_type_model_list

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have two Entities

Contacts:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use...

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"client", "name", "surname"},
 *     errorPath="name",
 *     message="This contact is already in use for this client."
 * )
 * @ORM\Table(name="contact")
 */
class Contact
{
  /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="client_id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $client;

/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, options={"default": ""}, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, options={"default": ""}, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $surname;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Email")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="email_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $email;

...

}
```

and Emails:

```
class Email
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="client_id")
     */
    private $client;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Email(
     *     message = "The email '{{ value }}' is not a valid email.",
     *     checkMX = true
     * )
     */
    protected $email;
...
}
```

I am using the "sonata admin bundle" to generate the GUIs.

For the ContactAdmin i have the following snippet:

...

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
    $formMapper
    ->add('email', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(
//                'query' => $query,
                'label' => 'E-Mail',
                'compound' => true,
                'by_reference' => true, 
                ))
```

The problem: When I add a new entry or choose one entry from the list - I do not want to select the "client" again. It has similar to the already choosen one.

I was able to access the pcode-Parameter in order to see if I have a parent class (Contact-Class for the Email-Class) - but how can I access the data which client has been choosen/selected by the parent-class?

Comment: You can also validate your case in `validate()` function there you will get current object with your selected choice and then check if already selected then show error or you can add a check of is ajax request on your client admin's `createQuery()` function and filter out the clients which you don't want to show in modal list